# FloatingActionButton on TextArea not working as expected

Tags: codenameone

I tried to use a `com.codename1.components.FloatingActionButton` in combination with a `com.codename1.ui.TextArea`.

Now I have two questions:

1. Apparently the valign is not honored - is it a bug?
2. The actionListener of the FloatingActionButton is not called. Is anything wrong with my usage or is it a bug?

Here is the code to demonstrate it:

```
public class FormFabOnText extends Form {
    public FormFabOnText() {
        setTitle("FormFabOnText");
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        Container contentPane = getContentPane();
        contentPane.add(BorderLayout.NORTH, new SpanLabel(
                "This form contains a TextArea and a FloatingActionButton combined by bindFabToContainer. "
                + "It demonstrates that the FloatingActionButton is not working in this constellation."));
        TextArea textArea = new TextArea();
        float iconDefaultSize = FloatingActionButton.getIconDefaultSize();
        try {
            FloatingActionButton.setIconDefaultSize(2.0f);
            FloatingActionButton floatingActionButton = FloatingActionButton.createFAB(FontImage.MATERIAL_CLEAR);
            Container containerFab = floatingActionButton.bindFabToContainer(textArea, Component.RIGHT, Component.CENTER);
            floatingActionButton.addActionListener((e) -> textArea.setText(""));
            contentPane.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, containerFab);
        } finally {
            FloatingActionButton.setIconDefaultSize(iconDefaultSize);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like the method `com.codename1.ui.Container.getComponentAt(int, int)` needs special treatment for LayeredLayout

Comment: Apparently `FloatingActionButton.pointerPressed` and `FloatingActionButton.pointerReleased` is called - so what is wrong?

Comment: The `FloatingActionButton` doesn't work when the `TextArea` is focused - then the `com.codename1.ui.Container.getComponentAt(int, int)` is not called at all

Comment: `com.codename1.ui.Form.pointerReleased(int, int)` is not called when a TextArea is focused. This is in the Simulator. But on an iPhone 5S the butten cannot be used either

Comment: You invested a lot of work in a great test case and description, a screenshot would have taken almost no additional effort and would have made a huge difference...

Answer (score 0):

The text area has 0 height so when you valign to the center the button correctly places itself on top. Then you add it to a border layout which stretches it across but the preferred size of the text area determines the valign so it stays.

I'm not sure if there is a good workaround for that other than a bit of margin like we did in the [msuikit demo](https://www.codenameone.com/demos-MSUIKit.html).

The issue with tapping during editing is probably related to the native editing peer. Tapping inside the text area gets sent to the native layer for editing otherwise elements below might cause an issue. Text input is a peer but also a very special case.

Comment: The container build by `bindFabToContainer` is `BorderLayout.CENTER` of the contentPane and thus should have a defined height. In both cases, I find it a pity that it does not work as expected, don't You think so?